# bug in the SQL parser

Tags: sql, wordpress, parsing, draw, cut

hello could somebody please tell me what should I do about this:

```
 Error
 There is a chance that you may have found a bug in the SQL parser. Please
 examine your query closely, and check that the quotes are correct and not mis-matched.
 Other possible  failure causes may be that you are uploading a file with binary   
 outside
 of a quoted text area. You can also try your query on the MySQL command line   
 interface.
 The MySQL server error output below, if there is any, may also help you in diagnosing
 the problem. If you still have problems or if the parser fails where the command line 
 interface succeeds, please reduce your SQL query input to the single query that causes
 problems, and submit a bug report with the data chunk in the CUT section below:

 ----BEGIN CUT----
 eNodzUsKwyAYBOBFdv8p5gBW1DQE3AWRZOGrmrYHCF0EgrtCe/ua7obhY8bmHLOGkTAKzgYNCQVF
 ZW1tR+S/5eY0Bi75KC7bcdC9ZMTCMM02rAwP2+BzrzBLjt42KXgvKPlJ49ryQGlJp2KxnDs9lyPc
 Xt8fclOYNV6V/hfU/QAEiiEJ
 ----END CUT----
 ----BEGIN RAW----
 ERROR: C1 C2 LEN: 1 2 2
 STR: 

 MySQL: 5.1.70-cll
 USR OS, AGENT, VER: Win CHROME 5.0.30
 PMA: 4.0.5
 PHP VER,OS: 5.3.17 Linux
 LANG: en
 SQL: 

 ----END RAW----

 SQL query:



 MySQL said: Documentation

 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
  your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

I've exported my Database as a backup and now when I import that I get this Error !! what's that? please tell me by the way I have some Arabic texts in my tables ...??

Comment: Did you change something in the sql file?

Comment: ya... but the problem is it's not working any more even with the unchanged version!

Comment: Versions of phpMyAdmin < 4.0.8 had problem with UTF8 exports. Try another dump

Answer (score 1):

Open the SQL document with any text editor and at the very end of the file, remove the blank lines (null characters). Save the file and you're good to go.

Source: https://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/bugs/4095/